# create event custom and send email to user automatically at a specified time

Tags: wordpress, sendmail

I intend to send an email to a user at a specified time.
I use wp_schedule_single_event to send email to user with this code:

```
function send_email() {
$to = "ex@example.com";
$subject = "test function wp_mail";
$message = "this is a body text massage....";
wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
add_action( 'event','send_email' );
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 180, 'event' );
```

But this email code is sent every three minutes and I do not want to be that way
And I just want to send an email once.

please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your code inside a function or a response otherwise it will 
schedule this event on every site visit :

```
 function send_email() {
  // send mail
}
add_action( 'event','send_email' );

// put this line inside a function, 
// presumably in response to something the user does
// otherwise it will schedule a new event on every page visit

 wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 180, 'event' );
```